# Issues with foundation-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I've generated a brand new rails app. I am using ruby version 2.3.3 and rails version 5.1.0 rc. Following the instructions on github:

1) I've added the foundation-rails gem to the gemfile

2) I've run the *bundle*  *install* command

3) Run the *rails g foundation:install* command

4) Added the following import to my *application.scss* file:

```
 @import "foundation_and_overrides";
```

5) Added the following statement to my *application.js* file:

```
//= require foundation
```

and the following statement to the my *application.js* file which is automatically generated by the install process:

```
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

6) After generating a simple home controller with the index action to start building the application I run the server and I get the following error:

[image]

Any help ? I'm trying and trying. Cannot sort out the issue.

Comment: restart your server and then check again.

Comment: please ref: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/issues/145

Comment: I did restart the server several times and already referred to the github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/issues/145 but nothing... it doesn't work. It's a mistery. I've seen that this issue had been raised all over the web. Moreover the Zurb Foundation site emphasized that their css framework is best suited for the rails backend framework.......I am a bit skeptical. Installation shouldn't be so problematic...

Comment: can you please write the name and the repo url of the foundation gem you are using?

Comment: this one https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which foundation gem you are using but I would suggest to fetch this kind of gems from rails-assets.org

You can check the below url for the installation and usage of zurb-foundation v6 gem.

https://rails-assets.org/#/components/zurb--foundation-sites

I hope it helps.